# Reference python global variable defined in a function --> from another file

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am using django social auth pipeline to introduce a custom function during the social authentication process. 
I am able to parse the request parameters (eg: the facebook user token) inside this function. The parsed token will serve as input for another function located in another file and here stands the problem: I can not use it in another function

I need to reference the global token variable from another function in another file. When I merge file1.py and file2.py , it works but when I want to use the parsed token from createUser(...) of file1.py in function doSomething() of file2.py, the interpreter throws an error which says that function createUser comes with arguments and I must define them , but how?

```
# settings.py:

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = [
    ...
    'MyApp.file1.createUser',
    ...
]

# file1.py :

from MyApp.models import FacebookUser
import file2

def createUser(backend, user, request, response, *args, **kwargs):
    if backend.name == 'facebook':

        global token
        token = request['token']

    if request['user_type'] == "facebookUser" and not FacebookUser.objects.filter(user_id=user.id):

        FacebookUser.objects.create(user_id=user.id)
        file2.doSomething()

    elif FacebookUser.objects.filter(user_id=user.id):
        file2.doSomething()


# file2.py :

from file1 import createUser

def doSomething():

    myToken = createUser().token   # <--- My problem is here. How can I access the global variable "token" from the createUser function in file1? The function createUser comes with arguments but how can I use it here?

    return myToken
```

Comment: You can't and you **must not** do this. There is no place for global variables in a multi-user environment like Python.

Comment: But your code makes no sense anyway. You have a circular dependency between these files which will make them impossible to import. Why don't your functions just accept parameters and return values?

Comment: Thank you Daniel. In fact I need to get that token and reuse it. I know that global is not a good practice. Can you suggest me a work around?

Comment: What is calling `createUser`? Why can't you return the token from that function? Why do you need it in file2? Why can't you call doSomething from createUser?

Comment: Maybe you want to create a class with the token as variable. In case you always have only one instance of this class you may want to use a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).